# insanely simple but impossible?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a square selection of vertices that i want to mirror along its right side so that it becomes a flipped repeat of my vertices that are joined in one mesh. Like this i have X and i want to make XX and using this process i want to eventually make a joined pattern like this: (ps im not making X's im making quilted furniture :)

XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX

This takes one klick in rhino3d.. well maybe 3 but its dead easy, mirror from point and then join, how is it done in blender?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: if you have one x, why can't you use the array modifier? or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes Array or duplicate with Auto-Merge and Snap to Vertex enabled